# In DS9, season 4, episode 19 "Shattered Mirror" why do the Klingons have such straight teeth?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, klingon

Why do all the Klingons in this episode have such nicely straightened teeth? Is this something peculiar to the alternate galaxy? It looks very strange to me...

Comment: Perhaps they don't kill their dentists in that universe!

Comment: You should attempt to put the question in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bit of a rolling occurrence throughout the post-TOS Star Trek series. It does appear quite a few of them have "immaculate" teeth.

I would suggest an "in-universe" theory would be that during the biological modifications the race underwent in the "early days" that some of them gained their slightly more human-like features during an effort to produce "the ultimate warrior" via the "augment" virus, which proceeded to change their appearance. This virus was based on modified human embryos produced during the Eugenics wars.